# Sharpness of the constant $1/6$ in Cancellation Theorem.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory

Let $\langle \; S \; | \; R \; \rangle$ be a presentation of a group $G$ with a set $R = R^{-1}$ of freely and cyclically reduced relators, and let $\Lambda$ be the girth of $\langle \; S \; | \; R \; \rangle$. Suppose that

1) the set $R$ of relators contains no proper power, and

2)  for any triple $x,y,z \in F(S)$ of reduced words, such that $yx$ and $zx$ are two distinct (reduced) cyclic conjugates of elements of $R$, we have $$|x| \leq 1/6 \Lambda,$$ where $|x|$ denotes the length of $x$.

Then, the famous **Cancellation Theorem** says that the corresponding *presentation complex* $P(S,R)$ is aspherical.

> Does anybody know if (and why) the constant $1/6$ in the statement is sharp?

To be more precise, I am not looking for an aspherical presentation that fails to meet condition $2$ (such are easy to construct). I am looking for a group with a non-aspherical presentation (in the above sense) that satisfies both conditions, but with constant $c > 1/6$.

---

Ideally, I am looking for an answer to the following question:

> For every $\epsilon > 0$, does there exist a presentation $P_{\epsilon}$ of a group $G_{\epsilon}$, satisfying both conditions, but with constant $1/6 + \epsilon$, such that $P_{\epsilon}$ is not aspherical?

Comment: What would you mean by "sharp" in this context? For example, it's elementary to write down a group with an aspherical presentation complex that fails to satisfy that condition.

Comment: Sure, but thats not what I mean. I am looking for a group which satisfies condition 1) and the same condition as 2) but with a constant $c > 1/6$ that is not aspherical.

Comment: I just want to be clear: you are *not* defining $C^{\prime}(1/6)$-presentations here, but are quoting the fact that $C(6)$-presentations are aspherical and then adding in the metric condition to see if there exist $C(5)$-presentations which are not aspherical but are arbitrarily close to being $C(6)$?

Comment: I think I may have found a solution to my question, compiling some well-known results in cancellation theory. Suppose that $\lambda > 1/6$ replaces $1/6$ in the above condition. If $\lambda \in (1/6,1/5)$, then condition $C(6)$ is still implied, which, along with the fact that no relator is a proper power, is (probably) sufficient to show that $P(S,R)$ is aspherical. If $\lambda \geq 1/5$, one can take the representation of the dodecahedron as the non-aspherical presentation.